# What does @nuxtjs mean in my eslintrc file?

Tags: nuxt.js, eslintrc

I am new to Nuxt.js and trying to understand what is meant by the following line (`@nuxtjs`) in my `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
extends: [
'@nuxtjs', <-------------------------- is this an alias?
'plugin:prettier/recommended'
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it just means that your eslint configuration will extend a eslint configuration named @nuxtjs ( e.g. it will have some preconfigured rules )

Here is github for eslint nuxt config https://github.com/nuxt/eslint-config